# SQL PIVOT TRANSFORMATION: How to order

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vba

I have been trying to make a table using TRANSFORM SQL in VBA Access. However, I would like to have my Pivot Key (the Top row) values to be ordered not based on alphabetic order but manually.
Here is my SQL code:

```
TRANSFORM Count(*) AS [Count]
SELECT MyQry.Period
FROM MyQry
WHERE ((MyQry.[Code]) ='A1' Or (MyQry.[Code])='A3' Or (MyQry.[Code])='A6' Or (MyQry.[Code])='A7' Or (MyQry.[Code])='A4')
GROUP BY MyQry.Period
ORDER BY MyQry.Period
PIVOT MyQry.[Code];
```

It gives me a Table as follow:

---

```
Period     A1       A3       A6       A7       A4
2015       5        10       8        9        0
2014       10       8        9        6        2
...        .        .        .        .        .
```

However, what I want to have is a table with the same periods and values but with table column values ordered like:

```
Period     A1       A3       A4       A6       A7
2015       5        10       0        8        9
2014       10       8        2        9        6
...        .        .        .        .        .
```

Also then I want to change the column name to:

```
Period     Primary       Secondary Code       Code A4       Code A6       Code A7
2015       5              10                   0              8             9
2014       10             8                    2              9             6
...        .              .                    .              .             .
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a conditional expression in the pivot clause to change the column headings like this:

```
TRANSFORM Count(*) AS [Count]
SELECT MyQry.Period
FROM MyQry
GROUP BY MyQry.Period
PIVOT 
    IIf([Code]='A1',"Primary Code",
    IIf([Code]='A3',"Secondary Code",
    IIf([Code]='A4',"Code A4",
    IIf([Code]='A6',"Code A6",
    IIf([Code]='A7',"Code A7","")))));
```

but the order of the columns would still be alphabetical. You code of course change the column headings to something that would sort the columns in the order you want (like "1. Primary", "2. Secondary", "4. Code A4" etc.), but that would change the column names in a way that might not be desired.

Another, and in my opinion better, option is to skip the transform/pivot altogether and instead use conditional expressions together with the count aggregate function like this:

```
SELECT 
    Period, 
    COUNT(IIF(Code='A1', Code, null)) AS [Primary Code],
    COUNT(IIF(Code='A3', Code, null)) AS [Secondary Code],
    COUNT(IIF(Code='A4', Code, null)) AS [Code A4],
    COUNT(IIF(Code='A6', Code, null)) AS [Code A6],
    COUNT(IIF(Code='A7', Code, null)) AS [Code A7]
FROM MyQry
GROUP BY Period
ORDER BY Period;
```

This gives you exactly what you want, and a lot more control over the output.